# How can I add a signature into an Outlook email with JavaScript mailto?

Tags: javascript, outlook, mailto

I am using JavaScript mailto function to fill an email body with custom text.

I can add text to the email but the signature doesn't show up.

Is there any way to send a custom signature with an image using mail-to function?
Or is there any way to insert an HTML image in the body when using the mail-to function?

Sample code:

```vb
var message = "text of message";                
var mailLInk = "mailto:sam@example.com?subject=subject&body=" + message;        
document.location.href = mailLink;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 2 of [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that the `body` field is supposed to be in `text/plain` format, so you can't do HTML.

However even if you use plain text it's possible that some modern mail clients would render the resulting link as a clickable link anyway, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, that information is stored in the outlook profile. Its up to Outlook (or some setting) on how to deal with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no way to send an html, because only plain text is accepted, and I can give you some tips why not to use mailto to send email:

Disadvantages of mailto in HTML

1. Mail address can be read by spam bots
2. Mailto only works if visitor have configured mail client
3. HTML mailto screams "This site is developed by begginer"

There is only one advantage and its easy to create and implement into web site. But if you want to use it just encode your mail address so it can't be read with spam bots.

But if you want to add footer in your mail message, then just in your body parameter add %0A, %0A is new line and your cursor will blink there so `?body=%0AThen your footer text` will give you footer in email.

:)