# How to place hyperlink in email signature

Tags: javascript, html

In Javascript I am opening my outlook to send one email on click of button.

My Email outllok is opening fine with all subject and Signature text.

I want to put one hyperlink of my work in sinature. Can any body please suggest how to make it

My code :

```
ClickEmail : function (){
    var Subject = "Test";
    var body = "";
    body = body + "   Name1  " + record.name[0] + "%0D%0A";
    body = body + "    Name1  " + record.name[0] + "%0D%0A";
    MyRecord  == window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Subject :'+Subject+'&body=My Body'+body 
}
```

Here after body I want to open lets take eample www.google.com

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `body = "<a href='mailto:xxx@yyy.com'>Email Me</a>"` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347701/how-can-i-add-a-signature-into-an-outlook-email-with-javascript-mailto

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Is there any way I can make use of hyperlink by using my stayle